# Windows Bootcamp Error, Audio and WiFi

Tags: macos, wifi, audio, bootcamp, bluetooth

I recently installed Windows using Bootcamp on my Macbook Pro 16".

1. The WiFi is very slow on the Bootcamp but fast on my macOS
2. I get distorted audio when I connect my Bluetooth headsets. But if I use the inbuilt speakers or wired headphones it works fine.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,

Dhruva

Comment: Have you installed all bootcamp updates?  In Windows run Apple Software update - and if there's a bootcamp update install it.  Also then in OSX have you run any firmware updates (if there are any), THEN in windows make sure you've got all windows updates.  If you don't have the latest drivers things might mis-behave ...  (there have definitely been bootcamp wifi & bluetooth updates in the past).

Comment: i do have all the latest updates installed